# Ansible script to spin up a failed instance in AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have a use case, where I have an EC2 instance with Fedora Linux and some applications running. When this instance fails, I have to spin up a new instance with the same OS and install the applications. I am trying to do in Ansible (and Python), I'm a complete novice and have no idea how to do it.

Comment: you need to use an auto scaling group

Comment: auto scaling doesn't fit my requirement entirely !

Comment: Do you want to make replica of existence instance?

Comment: yes! I want to make a replica !

Comment: we have license constraints with Auto scaling !

Answer (score 0):

For my applications, I have a variable (a structure) that tells me how many of each type of server I need in each of three subnets.  The environment creation playbook loops through that structure and builds however many are needed to fill the requirements.  So if I need five (5) and only have three (3), it builds two (2).  I use exact_count for that in the ec2 module.

So if one fails, I can delete that instance and re-run my create playbook, which will also re-write all the configuration files on the other servers that they use to communicate with each other.  For instance, if I delete a JBoss server create a new one to replace it, the load balancer has to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Good practise here would be to have a base image that covers what you need, use that as a feeder for an AMI, and then plug it into an Auto-scaling group. As part of the auto-scaling group, you can use `user-data` to load specific updates/etc onto the instance at boot time.

Autoscale group min 1 max 1 will do exactly what you want, if you can configure it the above way.